# Why this try catch example is not working

Tags: haskell, exception

I have following demo code from [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#exceptions):

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO  
import System.IO.Error  

main = toTry `catch` handler  

toTry :: IO ()  
toTry = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
           contents <- readFile fileName  
           putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"  

handler :: IOError -> IO ()  
handler e = putStrLn "Whoops, had some trouble!"
```

But it is giving me error:

```
runghc trycatch2.hs 

trycatch2.hs:5:14: error:
    Variable not in scope: catch :: IO () -> (IOError -> IO ()) -> t
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks.

Comment: You should `import Control.Exception(catch)`, you can see the name of the module at the top of the documentation, like [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catch).

Comment: Yes it works. They should have put it in demo code.

Comment: in the "early days", it was part of `System.IO.Error`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.0.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in [*Learn You a Haskell for the Greater Good*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#exceptions) is *outdated*, the [**`catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catch) function is part of [**`Control.Exception`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html).

[**`System.IO.Error`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html) however still has a catch function that is here applicable: [**`catchIOError :: IO a -> (IOError -> IO a) -> IO a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#v:catchIOError), but as the documentation says:

> The `catchIOError` function establishes a handler that receives any `IOException` raised in the action protected by `catchIOError`. An IOException is caught by the most recent handler established by one of the exception handling functions. These handlers are not selective: all `IOExceptions` are caught.
>
> (...)
>
> **Non-I/O exceptions are not caught by this** variant; to catch all exceptions, use `catch` from `Control.Exception`.

So you can fix the problem here by using `catchIOError` (since you are dealing with an `IOError`, but as specified in the documentation, this only covers a limited set of exceptions), or you can import `catch` from `Control.Exception`:

```
import Control.Exception(catch)

import System.Environment  
import System.IO  
import System.IO.Error

main :: IO ()
main = toTry `catch` handler  

toTry :: IO ()  
toTry = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
           contents <- readFile fileName  
           putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"

handler :: IOError -> IO ()  
handler e = putStrLn "Whoops, had some trouble!"
```